# implementing sign test in r for a small sample size

Tags: r, statistics

I have some non-parametric data with a small sample size. I would like to use the [sign test](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/BrownClasses/162/Handouts/StatsTests04.pdf) to test whether some variables are significantly different than 0. I have [seen examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test) were `binom.test` is used, but I am not sure how to implement it for my data test I am interested in.

I want to test if the median of the following data

```
data <- c(-300,-289,-315)
```

is significantly different than 0. Functions I have tried such as the `SIGN.test` don't work on my small sample size.

Is there a function in r I can use? If not how do I go about implementing `binom.test` with my data.

Comment: I don't have a good grasp of  your question.

Comment: @MarcoSandri median in this case because it is not parametric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sign Test has the null hypothesis that the median `M` is below some set value `M0`.  The Sign Test, then reduces to the binomial test where the number of successes is the number of values below `M0`.  With your data, you may perform

```
data <- c(-300,-289,-315)

binom.test(x = sum(!is.na(data)),
           n = sum(data < 0, na.rm = TRUE))

    Exact binomial test

data:  length(data) and sum(data < 0)
number of successes = 3, number of trials = 3, p-value = 0.25
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2924018 1.0000000
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                     1
```

Please note that your comparison is on the median, not the mean.

Comment: Is the high (i.e. not statistically significant) p-value due to the small number of samples? I would expect it to be low sense the numbers are so far away from 0.

Comment: The sign test is indifferent to magnitude of difference.  It only cares if it is above or below `M0`. If you wish to incorporate the magnitude, you should look at the Signed Rank test (`wilcox.test`).

Comment: Nevermind...that's wasn't a very intelligent comment. If you want to incorporate magnitude, you'll probably need to step away from nonparametric tests, which are primarily rank based.

Comment: I am not necessarily interested in magnitude. I don't think I am understanding what the p-value means here. Wouldn't it be small because all three values or successes are below 0?

Comment: No. because you only have three observations.  The large p-value means that you lack sufficient evidence to conclude that the median is less than 0. In other words, three observations is too few to be conclusive.

Comment: Thats the problem I been struggling with on this data. Is there a test that could conclude based on only 3 or 4 values?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, and not likely.  There's the _Because I want it to be_ test, but it isn't very robust.

Comment: As I figured but I was hopeful. Thanks.